# import/update large xml file into MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have about 30K records in an XML file and this file is updated all the time.

I'm trying to insert and if exists update a MySQL db.

This is the code I'd like to use, but it runs very slowly, does anyone have any ideas for improving its performance?

```
// getting xml file
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('products.xml');

// getting xml nodes using xpath
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$productid = $xpath->query('//NewDataSet/Product/ProductId');
$price = $xpath->query('//NewDataSet/Product/Price');

// Reading all nodes and if mach found in db update price, else insert as new record**
for($i=0;$i<$allNodes->length;$i++){
    $testproductid = $productid->item($i)->nodeValue;
    $testprice = $price->item($i)->nodeValue;
    if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("Select productid from test where productid ='$testproductid'"))){
        mysql_query("UPDATE test SET price = '$testprice' WHERE productid = '$testproductid'");
    }else{
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (price, productid) VALUES ('$testprice','$testproductid')");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need the `//` in `XPath`? It will also make things slow...

Comment: -1, SQL Injection. Prepared statements would probably make this significantly faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this line can result in bad behaviors:

```
if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("Select productid from test where productid ='$testproductid'")))
```

What happens if mysql_query() fails? Do something like that instead:

```
$res = mysql_query("Select productid from test where productid ='$testproductid'");
if ($res) {
... CODE HERE ...
}
```

Is *productid* an index? Also, you can formulate your query as:

```
Select productid from test where productid ='$testproductid' LIMIT 1
```

In this case, MySQL won't look for more records. Also, try to insert more than one record in on single INSERT statement. See this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html

Take a look at the REPLACE command. That would replace the SELECT/UPDATE/INSERT conditions, but it might not be a great improvement of performance though.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html

Comment: Hi, no productid is not index, its unique in xml but table has another index, because of that i cant use MySql REPLACE or DUPLICATE KEY or can I ?

Comment: Yes you can use. Why don't you make productid an UNIQUE index? It will speed up your queries a lot. Also, it's a good technique to disable the indexes before you run a lot of INSERT statements and then enabling them back, otherwise mysql would have to update the indexes at every INSERT statement.

Answer (score 0):

First off I recommend brushing up on some [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/). Second off, by using primary key on your 
`productid` field, you can use a more advanced sql statement called:
`insert ... on duplicate key update ...`

[It's gonna halve your database lookups for the first part](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), since you're doing one extra test before inserting/updating.

Second off, XML might not be the best solution for your cross-platform file. Any particular reason you are using this?

Answer (score 0):

Why do two queries where one will suffice?

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO test (price, productid) " .
       "VALUES ('$testprice','$testproductid') " .
       "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE";

if(!$query = mysql_query($sql))
   trigger_error(mysql_error());
```

You could also try [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) in place of [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), but from what I can Google there doesn't seem to be any documented speed difference.

Answer (score 0):

30k update statements in one transaction should complete in reasonable time (for waiting user). Perhaps autocommit is on?

Also, if you don't mind being mysql-specific there is REPLACE which does INSERT/UPDATE in one statement. Or you can do INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. In particular, this does away with "if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("Select productid from test where productid ='$testproductid'")))".

Comment: Hi, no productid is not index, its unique in xml but table has another index, because of that i cant use MySql REPLACE or DUPLICATE KEY or can I ? how turn of autocommit from php

Comment: If `productid` is unique, you should declare it as `UNIQUE` in the table. You can then use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you don't mind being mysql-specific there is `REPLACE` which does `INSERT`/`UPDATE` in one statement. Or you can do `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. In particular, this does away with `if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("Select productid from test where productid ='$testproductid'")))`.

30k update statements in one transaction should complete in reasonable time (for waiting user). Perhaps autocommit is on?

Comment: REPLACE is a combined DELETE/INSERT in one statement, which creates a new autoincrement value for the inserted row.

Answer (score 0):

Script to load a large files by chunks 
It will load the xml file, read a given number of entries in one time and then load them to the database..

```
$lot =5000;
$tempFiledir = '.';
$tempFile = 'temp.xml';
$table = 'mytable';
$db_username= 'root';
$db_password = 'mysql';

// count element 
    print( "    Computing items...");
    $xml_reader = new XMLReader;
    $xml_reader->open($xml_file);
    while ($xml_reader->read() && $xml_reader->name != $node_name);
    $totalItems =0;
    while ($xml_reader->name == $node_name) {
        $xml_reader->next($node_name);
        $totalItems++;
    }
    $xml_reader->close();

    print( "\r    $totalItems items found.                     ");


//Truncat the table to load into 
$xmlload_cmd = sprintf ("$mysql_exe -u%s -p%s $database_temp -e \"TRUNCATE TABLE `%s`;\" ", $db_username, $db_password, $table);
system($xmlload_cmd);                           

// move the pointer to the first item
$xml_reader = new XMLReader;
$xml_reader->open($xml_file);
while ($xml_reader->read() && $xml_reader->name != $node_name);


// load by chunks
$index = 0;
while ($xml_reader->name == $node_name){

    $tempFileXMLOutput = fopen( "$tempFiledir\\$tempFile", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    fwrite($tempFileXMLOutput,'<?xml version="1.0"?>');

    $index0=$index;
    do {    
        // remove self closign tags from the rendred xml output and store it in the temp file
        $data = preg_replace('/\<(\w+)\s*\/\s*\>/i', '<$1></$1>', $xml_reader->readOuterXML());
        fwrite($tempFileXMLOutput, "\n\t$data");    

        // move the pointer to the next item
        $xml_reader->next($node_name);
        $index++;
    }
    while ($xml_reader->name == $node_name && ($index % $lot != 0) );

    // close the temp file
    fclose($tempFileXMLOutput);

    echo sprintf("\r    Processing items from %6s to %6s [%3.0f%%]", $index0, $index, $index/$totalItems*100);

    // run the LOAD XML comand on the temp xml file
    $load_cmd = sprintf("LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '%s' INTO TABLE `%s` ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Data>'", addslashes("$tempFiledir\\$tempFile"), $table);               

    $xmlload_cmd = sprintf ("$mysql_exe -u%s -p%s $database_temp -e \"$load_cmd\" ", $db_username, $db_password);
    system($xmlload_cmd);   

    // remove the temp file
    @unlink ( "$tempFiledir\\$tempFile");
}

$xml_reader->close();
```